# Apple Error reporting suddenly turned off. OSX 10.9.4

Tags: macos, crash, error

So I was using my mac and usually when a game or application crashes it would produce an error report that will then allow me to either submit or not to apple.

Yesterday this stopped happening, some of my application have crashed and there have been absolutely no error reports whatsoever. I'm not entirely sure what has changed. Is there a way to check that error reporting is actually on? and if not, how do I turn it on?

Thanks!

Euden

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in Terminal. Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and then...

Turn the Crash Reporter dialog box off entirely:
`defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none`

Turn it back on to its default type:
`defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType crashreport`

Comment: This seems to work on the terminal however this doesn't seem to solve the problem, I know of a way that crashes the application I'm using every time, on my macbook which is 10.8 this produces an error report but on my iMac which is 10.9.4 this doesn't produce anything at all. Even after using said commands.